# Travelling to Netherlands with expired MVV

Tags: working-visas, netherlands

*This is my first time asking a question on this site. So I would request you to drop a comment / suggest an edit before downvoting or voting to close this question.*

I am currently working in India and my employer was about to send me to Netherlands for one year.

I have received MVV and I also have got my visas stamped with the v-number mentioned in MVV. I was supposed to be travelling on first week of this month -- May. But now, that is postponed.

Here is where I am confused.
- My MVV is valid from 27th February to 28th May -- end of this month.
- My Visa is valid from 2nd May to 1st July -- that is type D visa.
- I am yet to receive residence permit card / social security number. (of course)

So the questions are,
1. Do I still need a valid MVV to travel to Netherlands or my Visa has replaced it?
2. Would I be able to travel to Netherlands even if my MVV has expired? i.e after 28th of May?
3. If not, can I apply for the extension of MVV or do I have to reapply for MVV?